# Declaring array in class and using it

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I want to create an array in class `hash` and use it in its methods. I tried declaring it in `public` but still other methods are not able to access it. 
Here is my class declaration:

```
class hash
{   
    public:
    string hash_table[size]; //size is global variable;
    void initialize(int,string*,int); //I pass `hash_table` pointer and two other `int` type //arguments.
    int hash_function(string, int); 
    void quad_prob(int, int, string* , string); //`hash_table` array is used in this method also.
    void print(string*); //to print `hash_table` array

};
```

**I have to use array only.**
Also, can pleas explain when I use `hash h;` in `int main()`, what happens?
Here is complete code (without using class structure) : http://codepad.org/DQggdoI6

Comment: yes, but here by initializing means I am doing some operation on array before using other methods.

Comment: That is the constructors job

Comment: OK. I will copy code of `initialize` to constructor.

Comment: What do you mean, 'can't access it'? Please post the specifics of your problem?

Comment: `size` can't be a global variable - it must be constant, because size of `hash` type must be known in compile-time.

Comment: Take note on close votes, and provide a [SCCEE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @bmargulies It shows error: `hash_table was not declared in this scope.`

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, you've been missing a `;` in the array declaration and `hash_table` is not shown/seen!

Comment: @Nikhil And? Effect? Also, don't link outside SO for provision of code please ...

Comment: @Zifre I want to change `size` variable later in one of my methods. Initially, I want to use it to define array. Later, when I increase array size, `size` will change. (Note that size is one of the parameters in function `hash_function`.) So, I want to update `size` after certain operations during compilation. **So, I cannot declare it static**

Comment: @g-makulik It worked by that way but problem is defining `size` variable. When I use `static const int size` or initialize array like this [code](http://codepad.org/2Tc1engp) (It works on my compiler. You may ignore line #106) Then why it cannot work with declaration of `size` in `public:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to convert existing code to a class, yes?  Keep your `string hash_table[]` private in the class.  Then remove that parameter from each of the functions on codepad.  So `initialize`, as folks have pointed out, becomes the constructor `hash(int n, int size)` and initializes `hash_table` (`hash_table = new string[size]` or some such).  Similarly, `print` becomes just plain `print()`, and can refer directly to `hash_table` since it's a member function of the `hash` class.

Answer (score 1):

your array will be initialized when you create a new hash object. You would use hash h before any code using the object. When you make a new object, your constructor sets up your object for later use in your code. From there you should be able to use your code from your class.

Answer (score 0):

first I would suggest you use a vector.

Secondly once its defined in your class you just access it by name.

```
class foo
{
public: 
    foo(): vecfoo(5)
    {}
    void DoSomeThing()
    {
         for_each(begin(vecfoo),end(vecfoo),[](const string &){...});
    }
private:
    vector<string> vecfoo;


};
```

Comment: _'first I would suggest you use a vector.'_ He can't it's his homework assignment ...